# Sleeping shinyapp on shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny

How do I 'awaken' a sleeping shinyapp on shinyapps.io?

I have tried terminating and then (re)deploying. This does not work.

Answer (score 10):

I think that a sleeping shinyapp wakes up automatically when someone uses it.

Comment: That is my experience too

Answer (score 5):

Active hours are the number of hours that your application is up and serving requests. If you have one or one hundred people using your Shiny app for an hour, you are still only using one active hour. When an application hasn’t received any traffic for some time (the idle period) it will put itself to sleep which stops the active hour counter from accruing. When a user requests an application, shinyapps.io will “wake up” your application so that it is running and capable of servicing the request.

From [this](https://www.rstudio.com/faq-items/active-hour-shinyapps-io/), it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

That is my experience too. As soon as someone navigates to the application URL the application changes state from 'sleeping' to 'running'.